# How to intentionally make all Mirage JS request return 500?

Tags: http-status-code-500, miragejs

Trying to make MULTIPLE mocked service response 500 for testing any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Miragejs has a [Response class](https://miragejs.com/api/classes/response/) which you can instantiate and return from your response handlers. The first argument in the constructor is the status:

```
import { Response } from 'miragejs';

this.get('/users', () => {
  return new Response(500, { some: 'header' }, { errors: [ 'name cannot be blank'] });
});
```

Comment: I saw this in the docs as well but believe it or not I haven't been able to get it to work. It says the response is {
    "type": "default",
    "status": 200,
    "ok": true,
    "statusText": "",
    "headers": {
        "map": {
            "content-type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
        }
    },
    "url": "",
    "bodyUsed": false,
    "_bodyInit": 500,
    "_bodyText": "[object Number]"
}

Comment: I had the same response with Jonathan, after adding the import it worked !

Comment: it worked after adding import { Response } from 'miragejs'. I was missing the import statement and axios request was always going into then block. After adding the import, catch block got hit.